# How to send changed in DataGridView data to data base (Access) by clicking button?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, datagridview

I have seen lots of questions and answers about this but just can't get what's wrong with my code.

I display tables from database this way:

```
public void refreshTable() {
            string conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=db.mdb";
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM " + 
                comboBox1.Text, connection); //comboBox1 have table name

            connection.Close();

            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(dataSet);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
            adapter.Update(dataSet);
        }
```

Everyone tell about this: http://tech.pro/tutorial/664/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-database

I tried to use code from this link this way:

```
private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            string conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=db.mdb";
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + 
                comboBox1.Text, connection);

            BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
            DataTable dTable = new DataTable();

            adapter.Fill(dTable);
            bSource.DataSource = dTable;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;

            adapter.Update(dTable);
        }
```

All looks fine, but as i press button (call saveButton_Click), all changes i have done in DataGridView is undo and data base still the same. So basicly it just again load DataGridView from data base to DataGridView.

But if i write in DataGridView something incorrect (key value "asdasd" or date "qwer") program show me exception.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: In your second code, don't load and bind data in the saveButton_Click. you should have a loadButton_Click to initialize your DataGridView, then user may edit the gridView, finally save it in saveButton_Click with the update command. Input errors triggers a DataError event that you should handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally get it.

```
public FormExemple : Form
{
    protected string conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=db.mdb";
    protected OleDbConnection connection;
    protected OleDbDataAdapter adapter;
    ....

    Window_Load()
    {
        connection = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
        ...
        adapter.Fill(dTable);

        cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
        adapter.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand();
        //and other commands
        ...
    }

    Button_Click()
    {
        ...
        adapter.Update(dTable)
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is in VB and Mysql server but the basics of ADO are the same

```
Dim CS As New MySqlConnection(My.Settings.myConnectionString)
Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + 
            comboBox1.Text, CS)
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim cmb As New MySqlCommandBuilder(da)
Dim tableNamesBS As New BindingSource

    Try
    da.Fill(ds, "test")
    datagridview1.DataSource = ds.Tables("test")
    tableNamesBS.DataSource = ds.Tables("test")

        Dim x As Integer
        da.UpdateCommand = cmb.GetUpdateCommand
        x = da.Update(ds.Tables("test"))
        MsgBox(x & "Record(s) Updated")
    Catch ex As Exception
        msgbox("Error in " & ex.message)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

You are loading and filling the data again in Save button Click event thats why all the updated changes is wiped out.

Have Load and Save(Update) events in different subs/functions with common variables.

So LoadData() will be

```
//Global variable for adapter;
DataSet dataSet;
public void LoadData() {
            string conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=db.mdb";
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM " + 
                TABLE_NAME, connection); 

            connection.Close();

            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            dataSet = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(dataSet);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];

        }
```

Then in UpdateData function

```
public void UpdateData()
{
    adapter.update(dataSet);
}
```